# Reading multiple FM Radio Channels simultaneously

Tags: pi-3

I'd like to use the Pi to make an FM radio but I also want to be able to read multiple frequencies with the Pi at the same time. Is this possible through using SDR and antenna and software? Or should I look into some sort of physical multiplexor that is compatible with the Pi?

Comment: The SDR reads the whole spectrum (in the range it can cover), but if you can usefully process multiple broadcasts at the same time on the Rpi, I do not know. With just audio it might be possible.

Answer (score 2):

Devices decoding several transmissions at once are called "skimmers". There are readily available SDR skimmers for continuous wave signals, like telegraphy or Morse code.

Multi-channel FM reception is significantly more complex because of non-trivial modulation. You may take a look at [MultiFM](https://github.com/pvachon/tsl-sdr/wiki/Using-MultiFM) project and see if you can get it working on an RPi.